# Simple Python App Engine Server with Directory Routing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm very new to app engine and python.  I've gone through the tutorials, but haven't been able to find a simple/elegant solution for what I'm looking for.

I want to make a website that has multiple directories:

```
/home
   /index.html
/stuff
   /index.html
/otherstuff
   /index.html
```

I know I can do this easily if in my app.yaml file I do:

```
- url: /otherstuff
    script: account/otherstuff.py

- url: /stuff
    script: game/stuff.py

- url: .*
    script: home.py
```

My problem with this is that it is not an elegant solution since I will have 3 python files to serve up simple html files.  Instead I was hoping just to have one python file that routes my get requests to the appropriate directory.  Since I'm such a newb to app engine and python - I was hoping someone would be willing to shed some light on how to do this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you mark the files as *static* you don't need to serve them via python, you can call them directly. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html files are static files, then you don't need to serve them via Python. (as Paul Collingwood pointed out)

However, if you insist on using Python maybe for the learning factor of it, or your html files are dynamic. 
Here is a suggestion.

In your app.yaml file you can state:

```
handlers:
- { script: main.app, url: /.* }
```

Where main is your python file name, and app is the variable name within the python file.

Create a main.py file with contents:

```
import webapp2

class HomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("<h1>Hello</h1>")
        return

class StuffHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("<h1>Stuff</h1>")
        return

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
        ('/', HomeHandler),
        ('/stuff/', StuffHandler)
    ],
    debug=True
)
```

This should give you the idea.

You should serve html pages via templates to separate your html with your python code. 
You can use jinja2 library to do so.

An example for simple html jinja2 template check out: http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=1338

hope that helps.
cheers.

**UPDATE:**

If you would like it to be dynamically catching the name you can do this:

```
class DynamicHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, stuff):
        self.response.write('This is the DynamicHandler. '
           'The string is %s' % stuff)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
      (r'/', HomeHandler),
      (r'/(.*)', DynamicHandler)
    ],
    debug=True
)
```

This should give you an idea on how to handle the directory name.

In regards to handling 404, normally you can add this line at the end. ( after app=webapp2....)

```
def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    response.write('This is not the droid you are looking for')
    response.set_status(404)

app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
```

But since our regex is very broad,  you have to handle everything within DynamicHandler (i.e. if someone typed /droid if will satisfy the regex), you have to raise your own exception within DynamicHandler

Please see this page for webapp2 exceptions handling

https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html

As a suggestion, I wouldn't go as broad/dynamic as above example myself, but hope that helps you to do what you want.

cheers.

Comment: Wan - Thanks so much for the thorough response.  I indeed believe this approach is more elegant than serving up static files.  Within the main.py - is there a way to handle directories like 'stuff' or 'otherstuff' in a more dynamic way?  Hardcoding the names doesn't seem ideal.  Also - how would I catch a 404 in order to send them to a 404 template?

Answer (score 0):

[Flask-FlatPages](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-FlatPages/) does more or less what you want, but actually, there's no reason for you to host a static site on App Engine.